# New laptop with an hd display, everything is microscopic

Tags: windows-7, resolution, high-resolution

I've just purchased a laptop with a 15.6" UltraSharp FHD (1920x1080) LED display, and everything looks like it's massively zoomed out. A temporary fix, changing the font display size to "larger" has restored everything to a legible status, but now a slightly more obnoxious problem has arisen. Some interfaces don't play nicely and scale like they should, and text is often cut off and GUIs are totally messed up.

I've tried modifying the screen resolution but that simply uses up less space on the monitor.

Any way to make text normal sized while utilizing the full size of the display and still keeping the graphics smooth and non-pixelated, short of purchasing a new laptop? That's not even an option for fixing this.

Comment: Not really. Your best option is to return the laptop and get one with a lower resolution. Windows 7 should have been configured with font scaling at 150% out of the box, but apps that don't support Vista/7's font scaling won't look so hot.

Comment: I wouldn't want a resolution that high on anything less than 22"...

Comment: Modified the question slightly, given these comments.

Comment: Except for [increasing font scaling](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Make-the-text-on-your-screen-larger-or-smaller) (and dealing with apps that don't cope properly with this), I don't see any other alternative (other than getting used to it).

Comment: 15.6" x 1920x1080 OMG, you better have 20-20 vision