# Increase font scaling on a per-program basis

Tags: windows-7, fonts

This is a followup to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/429280/new-laptop-with-an-hd-display-everything-is-microscopic). I can deal with the system font being small since it's fairly large anyway, but I'd like to increase font scaling for programs like Chrome and Skype and only those.

My reasoning behind wanting to only scale those is, they're ridiculously tiny and hard to read, and now I can't play half my Steam library (I know, terrible reason to be worried about fixing this. Lots of games don't scale properly though).

How can I increase font size only for particular programs?

Comment: Fun side note: As of one minute ago, this is already on the first page of google results for various phrasings of this question. Mother of SEO....

Answer (score 3):

If the given program's Settings can change the font, or its User Interface lets you zoom-in, you are in luck.

Otherwise, I fear that there is no solution to the problem, except maybe using a screen magnifier.

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is just font scaling, I don't think this can be done smoothly. For Chrome you can adjust the text size directly in Chrome without changing the zoom level. If you go to the Settings -> Advanced Settings, under Web Content you can change the text size. Windows doesn't allow you to change DPI settings or font scaling on a per-program basis. It is determined on a system basis (or user). Windows 7 allows you to scale the desktop to 125% and 150% but that doesn't always work well. There is also a custom DPI scaling setting that's not so easy to find. If you go to Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Display, then on the left side there is an option for "Set custom text size (DPI). This will allow you much more fine-grained control over the DPI settings. Although this may increase the Windows system font as well, you may have more like finding a sweet spot between your Skype and games font and Windows system fonts. I hope this helps. It's also extremely likely that since it's a game, it doesn't adhere to Windows system font settings. You may just need to play at a lower resolution, or get a larger monitor with a lower DPI count.